# Set the ArrayList value to the RadioButton in the for loop

Tags: android, arraylist

I am getting `arrayList [5,8,13,18,19]` from the server and I would like to create a `RadioGroup` in the xml file. After selecting the diserable items, I will put the selected items in `arrayList` and transmit the query to the server after clicking the OK button. How can I create such as programmatically `RadioGroup`?

I have tried this but I dont know how to loog through to set the `RadioButton` with the `ArrayList` value. How can I get that tp work?

```
private void createRadioButton(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {

    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
    final ArrayList<RadioButton> rb = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); // create the RadioGroup
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);// or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        items.get(i) = new RadioButton(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the number of items is arbitrarily big, use a `RecyclerView` instead of a "simple" ViewGroup like RadioGroup for displaying the items. Because creating a View for _every_ item will take a lot of time and memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
    final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); // create the RadioGroup
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);// or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
        rb.setText(items.get(i)+"");
        rg.addView(rb);
    }
```

With the `addView` you are adding the dynamically created `RadioButton` to the `RadioGroup`.

Comment: How can I add the RadioButton underneath the other?  I have tried like this `rb.setText(items.get(i) + "\n");` but it does not work.

Comment: Did you try changing `RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL` to `RadioGroup.VERTICAL`? You have it commented in your code.